# Замена div в зависимости от checked radio button

Tags: javascript, css, html, switch

Есть 2 радио кнопки:

```
<div id="donate3">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle1"checked="checked"><span></span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle1"><span></span></label>
</div>
```

И есть `div`, отображать который необходимо в зависимости от активированного радио.
Вопрос: как объяснить JS какая кнопка включена, если у них одинаковые `name="toggle1"`?
Если дать уникальные имена, радио работает как чекбокс и только на ВКЛ.

Answer (score 5):

Вот как то так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/5rcvp/

```js
$('#donate3 input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  var k = $(this).parent().index();
  $('#result').text('Активна: ' + k);

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="donate3">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="toggle1" checked="checked">Donate
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="toggle1">Me
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="toggle1">Please
  </label>
</div>

<div id="result">Активна: 0</div>
```

Comment: Можно чуть оптимизировать, чтоб каждый раз не искать родительский элемент:
    
    `var inp = $('#donate3 input[type=radio]');
    inp.change(function () {
        $('#result').text('Активна: ' + inp.index(this));
    });`